# All subgroups of a symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I am very new to the theory of groups and am writing a program that generates all subgroups of the symmetric group $S_n$; the idea is to find the generators for each subgroup.

With this thread, I was hoping to get some ideas about the following questions:

1. Does there exists a way to pick the generators beforehand to avoid
   recomputing the same subgroups?
2. If so, what would be a could starting point for me?

Currently, I am picking the set of generators by some arbitrary set of permutations from $S_n$.

Comment: Permutations are generated by transpositions, so instead of choosing a set of generators, choose a set of transpositions(i.e., $\sigma _k =12\cdots (k-1)\underbrace{(k+1)k}_{\text{notice they are exchange}}(k+2)\cdots n \in S_n$)

Comment: @Phicar A subgroup does not necessarily contain any transposition, think e.g. $A_n$.

Comment: Generating all subgroups of $S_n$ is going to be a really hard problem.

Comment: I wouldn't try it for $n$ large. There are an awful lot of subgroups.

Comment: It would be nice to get it working for $n \leq 10$

Comment: @Berci Sorry, that's right.